# How to upload only updated files from a localhost to a web-server?

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I am working on a website. I do most of my development works from the localhost. Usually whenever I have to update the website, I delete all files on the server and upload everything from the website folder to the server. Previously, the files were less so it was not a problem, but now the files are large and it takes quite a lot of time to upload all files. Is there any way/software that would help me upload only the updated files? My website is based on PHP and MySQL. Thanks - this is my first post.

Comment: Why you just dont't download the file in which you want to make changes, and then upload that file ?

Comment: Working with localhost. And I have made changes to many files - but rather little changes. I don't want to reupload everything just for those little changes.

Comment: Why not using version control or remote file system?

Comment: using Git now as referred by Nick.

Answer (score 1):

You should use any version control system to manage all such cases.

There are so many wonderful tools available for version control like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/), SVN etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work with Cobian Backup using an incremental Backup to the webserver. Just create a task and the program uploads everything that changed since the last "backup".

Comment: Newbie to Cobian Backup. But sure will check it out.

Comment: GIT is the better solution, but as I am using Cobian for backups I also use it for sync with my webserver because you can create batchfiles to run tasks.